# Stuck with LNK1328: missing string table

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors, libvlc

With `dumpbin.exe` on `libvlccore.dll` I get:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1328: missing string table

and I have no idea how to solve this. (googling for hours now), but I only get this on the `INSTALL` target.  The app builds fine and uses VLC. (I do have some VLC related run time errors I'm trying to solve.)

My target is a MSVC 12 x86_64 application, I'm using VLC via VLC-Qt.

Do I need a `.def` file?  Or is this a sign of some incompatibility?

My `PATH` seems to have nothing to do with this, *i.e.* having the dll and lib in the same directory has no impact.

I found a [very similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686332/vlc-api-with-c-linker-error-for-lib-even-when-ive-added-it-to-my-vc-pro?rq=1) but nothing in the comments helped.

I downloaded VLC from [here](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/3.0.4/win64/).  The SDK provides the `.lib` file which in the past (years ago) I had to manually create.